# How to update multiple select in Laravel 7

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am updating a field where I am using a multiple select drop down. Now, I don't know how to update it. Here in my controller code. I am receiving `$request->doc_user_edit` as an array from my edit form. I am checking it if it's the same with the database values or not.

Controller:

```
 $chk_doctor = DoctorSecrectaryLine::where('secretary_id', $decoded_userId)->value('doctor_id');

            $form_doc = $request->doc_user_edit;
            
                    if($chk_doctor == $form_doc){
                        $update_user = DB::table('users')->where('id',$decoded_userId)->update([
                            'first_name' => $request->first_name,
                            'middle_name' => $request->middle_name,
                            'last_name' => $request->last_name,
                            'suffix' => $request->suffix_name,
                            'house_no' => $request->house_no,
                            'street' => $request->street,
                            'barangay_id' => $request->barangay,
                            'municity_id' => $request->municity,
                            'province_id' => $request->province,
                            'contact_no' => $request->contact,
                            'email' => $request->email,
                            'username' => $request->username,
                            'user_type_id' => $user_type,
                            'gender' => $request->gender_edit,
                            'birthdate' => $request->birth_date_edit,
                        ]);
                        $msg = 'Secretary updated successfully!';
                        return redirect()->route('Users.index')->with('success',$msg);

                    }else{
                        $update_user = DB::table('users')->where('id',$decoded_userId)->update([
                            'first_name' => $request->first_name,
                            'middle_name' => $request->middle_name,
                            'last_name' => $request->last_name,
                            'suffix' => $request->suffix_name,
                            'house_no' => $request->house_no,
                            'street' => $request->street,
                            'barangay_id' => $request->barangay,
                            'municity_id' => $request->municity,
                            'province_id' => $request->province,
                            'contact_no' => $request->contact,
                            'email' => $request->email,
                            'username' => $request->username,
                            'user_type_id' => $user_type,
                            'gender' => $request->gender_edit,
                            'birthdate' => $request->birth_date_edit,
                        ]);
                        $doc_id = $request->doc_user_edit;
                        $rem_sec = DB::table('doctor_secrectary_line')->where('doctor_id',$chk_doctor)->update(['secretary_id' => NULL,]);
                        $insert_doctorToDocSecLine = DB::update("UPDATE doctor_secrectary_line set secretary_id = ? WHERE doctor_id = ?",[$decoded_userId,$doc_id]);
                        $msg = 'Secretary data updated and is transferred!';
                        return redirect()->route('Users.index')->with('success',$msg);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

nvm I got it. For people searching for this here is my solution:

```
 if ($request->doc_user_edit === null) {
                    DoctorSecrectaryLine::where('secretary_id', $decoded_userId)->update(['secretary_id' => NULL]);
                } else {
                    DoctorSecrectaryLine::where('secretary_id', $decoded_userId)->update(['secretary_id' => NULL]);
                    DoctorSecrectaryLine::whereIn('doctor_id', $request->doc_user_edit)->update(['secretary_id' => $decoded_userId]);
                }
```